# Questions about migration from SP 2007 to 2010 that use both the version tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging

Probably I am thinking to much here, but I prefer to ask for guidance anyway.
I was reading some old discussion about the version tags (2010/2007 ecc) and I had the (probably bad) idea to check if any question used both the two  main version tags.

[As you can see](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010+2007) this query currently returns 16 questions. Most of them seems to be questions about migrating contents and other elements from SharePoint 2007 to 2010.

I get that the version tag problem has been already discussed in the past, but I don't get how we should act *in this specific case*. Question about migration process tends to be specific to the start and end version (or at last many of them do)... what is the general opinion? Anyone (Jeff?) has ever consider this case in the past?

We could just retag them with a generic "migration" tag, but I fear that it wouldn't be sufficient (I haven't had the time to read all the double-tag question, so I am not refering to any specific question). Any older (and more experienced) user can suggest a solution here (or redirect me to some other post, have searched for a similar question but I found nothing)?

Comment: The only thing worse than a version tag... is TWO version tags! :P

Comment: that search doesnt return any hits? *innocent whistle*

Comment: @AndersRask maybe *someone* retagged them.... but as what ^_^'?

Comment: Not alot of those posts were specific for migration, but i retagged some with Upgrade (migration is more specific related to content migraton than a farm upgrade)

Comment: @AndersRask Ok, then we should simply tag such question as upgrade disregard the specific version? I can see the logic (to avoid the usual version tag problem) but... Shouldn't we at last edit the title to provide some indication of the affected version? Something like *(2007->2010)* - it wouldn't affect tagging, but at the same time would provide version info without the need to open the question.

Comment: that would be part of either title or content. For arguments pro/con version tagging, look at earlier threads regarding that topic [here](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-we-tag-questions-with-a-sharepoint-version) and [here](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142/version-tags-considered-harmful)

Comment: @AndersRask yes, I saw those (btw, you forgot the [follow up](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok) ^_^). I was just elaborating if when editing the version tags we should nuke them from orbit or leave a subtle trace of their existance in the question title (at last **when it make sense**).